# How to clean and edit JSON file via nodejs

Tags: node.js, json

I have a JSON file that contains some data that I need to remove:

```
{
    "Count": 2, 
    "Items": [
        {
            "character": {
                "S": "1234"
            }, 
            "location": {
                "S": "east"
            }, 
            "inputs": {
                "S": "1"
            }, 
            "region": {
                "S": "north"
            }, 
            "access": {
                "S": "0"
            }  "S": "physical"
        }
    ], 
    "ScannedCount": 2, 
    "ConsumedCapacity": null
}
```

What I want to remove is everything outside of the [ ] brackets from Items

Comment: `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(YOUR_FILE)["Items"], null, 4)`

Comment: that only returned "Items". Im trying to get the array inside items

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work. Thank you @Zero298 for the initial idea.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var newJSON = '';
newJSON = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('my_file.json', 'utf8'))['Items'], null, 4);
console.log("THIS IS THE NEW JSON");
console.log(newJSON);
```